# Видео-фон для секции сайта

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, видео, background

Добрый день!

Возникла необходимость сделать короткое видео (15-20 сек) для фона части сайта. Но, большинство решений, которые предлагает интернет, рассчитаны на статичный "видеофон" для всего сайта, либо "паралаксное" видео шапки. Короче говоря, ничего подходящего не нашел.

Есть элемент `section` и нужно чтобы вместо обычного "background-а-картинки" у него на фоне проигрывалось зацикленное короткое видео, секция растянута на 100% ширины страницы и имеет какую-то фиксированную высоту, а поверх него было обычное наполнение секции, формы, параграфы и т.д. и чтобы это все пролистывалось как обычная секция. Как это можно реализовать? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Можно, банально алхимия с `video` ( http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp ). Но юзать видео в вебе как элемент интерфейса - это плохая затея. Если уж так сильно надо - нарежьте видео как `gif`.

Comment: Спасибо за идею с gif, оказалось весьма полезно.